# Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/library_release.kotlin_module

Tags: android, kotlin, conflicting-libraries

I recently added two Android libraries through JitPack and I have the following error:

```
Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/library_release.kotlin_module
```

I've cleared the cached and I've tried excluding the module using

```
exclude group: 'org.jetbrains'
```

and

```
exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin'
```

but neither seems to resolve the issue. Is there any way to stop the kotlin stdlib from being added through JitPack? Oddly, other libraries like DbFlow don't have this issue, though I don't see anything special about their setup (other than that it isn't through JitPack)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should add this to the `build.gradle` file of your app inside the `android` tag

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/library_release.kotlin_module'
}
```

Comment: Do you know if the file itself has any significance in the app? Or is it just there as info?

Comment: I never seen a problem excluding those META-INF files in Android. Btw i don't know Kotlin enough to be sure that this is useless at 100%. As i suggested in the other comment, you should try with exclude first, if it is working continue to use it (the app will be lighter by some KBs XD), if not switch to pickFirst ;)

Comment: Doesn't it mean that when we switch to different buildType or productFlavor the same error appears again because it generates files with new names?

Comment: leads to Kotlin classes not being recognized

Comment: kotlin module file contains some kotlin meta data such as top level function, top level property, if you using exclude solution, you will get a "Unresolved reference" build error. Not sure whether kotlin module file contains other info @MatPag

Answer (score 19):

As suggested in the post [Kotlin M13 is out!](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/09/kotlin-m13-is-out/) by `jetbrains`:

> Make sure these .kotlin_module files are not stripped by your packaging process.

So, we can't use `exclude` option to exclude this resource file from being generated.

As descripted in [Kotlin M13 is out!](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/09/kotlin-m13-is-out/), we should:

in Maven we use groupId and artifactId for module names, but you can say

```
<configuration>
    <moduleName>com.example.mymodule</moduleName>
</configuration>
```

in Gradle it’s project name + build task name, to customize:

```
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.moduleName = "com.example.mymodule"    
}
```

This is my configuration for `Android` library project:

```
ext {
    GROUP_ID = 'custom.group.id'
    ARTIFACT_ID = 'artifactid'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    compileOptions {
        kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs += ['-module-name', "$GROUP_ID.$ARTIFACT_ID"]
    }

    defaultConfig {
        ...
    }
    buildTypes {
        ...
    }
}
```

Resource file named `META-INF/custom.group.id.artifactId.kotlin_module` will be generated instead of `META-INF/library_release.kotlin_module`.No more duplicate files will be found.

You can read this [post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/09/kotlin-m13-is-out/) and this [post](https://deskid.github.io/2019/03/05/about-kotlin-module/) for more information.

Comment: Yes, adding compileOptions {
        kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs += ['-module-name', "$GROUP_ID.$ARTIFACT_ID"]
    }
fixes problem

And I think it's better than just exclude

Comment: I tested both solutions (exclude and this one) and both of them work and have no apparent side effects. Can somebody please provide any additional arguments - or example - why one is better over another?

Comment: kotlin module file contains some kotlin meta data such as top level function, top level property, if you using exclude solution, you will get a "Unresolved reference" build error. Not sure whether kotlin module file contains other info @ror

Answer (score 10):

After looking at other conflicts, it seems like the resolution is

```
packagingOptions {
    pickFirst 'META-INF/library_release.kotlin_module'
}
```

under `android` in the app gradle.

This allows the apk to build